# Mac Mail Client sending and storing duplicates from Gmail

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, imap, pop

One of my team members approached me today asking about an issue they're having with their Mac Mail Client and Gmail. I am a Linux user and do not have much experience with Mac, but thought I would reach out to this community on their behalf.

- User aggregating 3 email addresses into Mac Mail (Gmail Personal, Gmail Professional, Hotmail)
- All email providers set up properly as IMAP (POP on phone)
- User experiences duplicates in both Sent folder
- User's Drafts folders has incomplete information (some emails are missing)
- Mail Server information appears to be correct

**Thoughts**

I am thinking that this might be an issue with IMAP vs. POP, but I figure that the Sent folder would be suffering from similar issues. What

Comment: How are the mails compared to the online gmail client? Does that look correct compared to Apple Mail?

Comment: The emails are exact duplicates - no changes in text or HTML form. 

What is your reason for asking? Do you think it might be a forwarding issue?

Comment: I meant the mailboxes and how the mails add up there compared to the Apple Mail. Are there duplicates in the web interface as well? Same mails missing?

Comment: @Hoshts Thank you for the clarification - The duplicates are only showing up in Apple Mail.

Comment: Ok. So the online gmail accounts look correct then. That is good and sounds more like there is a problem with Apple Mail and not syncing. Have you tried to rebuild the mail database in the application?